# Masking Invalid Actions when using Stable Baselines

Tags: pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I am attempting to set up an environment for an RL problem using `stable-baselines`. Assume that the action space consists of several groups of actions as follows.

Group 1: 30 actions
Group 2: 30 actions
Group 3: 100K actions
Group 4: 30 actions

In a single episode, the agent is allowed to pick an action from each group, until an action has been chosen from all groups. Once an action has been selected from a group, it cannot select from that group until the episode ends and the environment is reset. There is also a "DONE" action allowing the agent to end the episode early before choosing from all groups.

My question is, how do I prevent the agent from selecting multiple actions from the same group when using stable-baselines?

I have tried penalizing the reward as `-inf` when selecting an invalid action, but the agent keeps getting stuck in Group 3 due to the massive number of actions, resulting in the episode continuing indefinitely. When I implemented a DQN from pure PyTorch, I was able to manually mask the output logits of the model and set the probabilities of actions to 0, but I do not have that access when using stable-baselines.

Answer (score 0):

In the sb3-contrib repository, you have an algorithm that allows the use of masking invalid actions: [MaskablePPO](https://sb3-contrib.readthedocs.io/en/master/modules/ppo_mask.html). It isn't DQN, but it should work in a similar way in some environments.

About creating a masked DQN implementation, this is still an open issue that you can find [here](https://github.com/Stable-Baselines-Team/stable-baselines3-contrib/issues/16).

Comment: I don't see any mention of maskable DQN on the issue you linked